# Trouble deparsing Perl encrypted with Filter::Crypto::Encrypt

Tags: decryption

I am trying to use `perl -MO=Deparse` to get readable source code from encrypted Perl files.

The Perl script I'm trying to deparse starts with `use Filter::Crypto::Decrypt;`.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Can't run with Perl compiler backend at /System/Library/Perl/5.18/XSLoader.pm line 95. 
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Filter/Crypto/Decrypt.pm line 37.
```

When reading [this webpage](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Filter-Crypto-2.06/Decrypt/lib/Filter/Crypto/Decrypt.pm), it says:

> **Can't run with Perl compiler backend**
>   (F) The encrypted Perl file is being run by a perl with the Perl compiler backend enabled, e.g. perl -MO=Deparse file. This is not allowed since it may assist in retrieving the original unencrypted source code.

If I understand this correctly, then this is a security measure to prevent people from doing exactly what I'm trying to do. Correct? Is there any way to override this?

Comment: I think you could [decrypt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28718897/encrypted-perl-scripts-by-filtercrypto-crypt-file-usage-on-other-machines) it first before running Deparse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is an intended prevention and there's no technical limitation behind this error message, it should be easy enough to just patch out the explicit check in the `perl` executable. You could then have your own version of perl that allows the decryption of the perl program and exposes the original source code.